# Solve a system of quadratic and trigonometrc equations

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

I have a condition

$$3R^2-d^2+2dR\cos\alpha = 0$$

along with the following equations

$$d = \sqrt{(X_1-X_2)^2+(Y_1-Y_2)^2}$$ 
$$\alpha = \arccos{\frac {Y_2-Y_1}{d}}+\psi$$ 
$$Y_2=Y_1-(X_1 - X_2)\tan\psi $$

The values $ X_1, Y_1, \psi, R$ are known.

The resolution of the first condition should lead to a second order equation for $X_2$. The solution obtained for $X_2$ is of interest.

Tried solving it with little success, someone help me out.

Comment: You want to solve this System of equations for $X_2,Y_2,d$?

Comment: Yes, since $Y_2, d$ can be expressed in terms of $X_2$, obtaining the solution for $X_2$ is the goal.

Comment: This is the Output by Mathematica, i hope this will help you: $$\left(\left(0=d-\sqrt{d^2}\land \psi =\alpha -\frac{\pi }{2}\land \text{X2}=\frac{-\sqrt{d^2
   \left(\cot ^2(\alpha )+1\right)}+\text{X1} \cot ^2(\alpha )+\text{X1}}{\cot ^2(\alpha
   )+1}\right)\lor \left(0=d-\sqrt{d^2}\land \psi =\alpha -\frac{\pi }{2}\land
   \text{X2}=\frac{\sqrt{d^2 \left(\cot ^2(\alpha )+1\right)}+\text{X1} \cot ^2(\alpha
   )+\text{X1}}{\cot ^2(\alpha )+1}\right)\right)\land \text{Y1}=\text{X1} \tan (\psi
   )-\text{X2} \tan (\psi )+\text{Y2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I did not really understand the solution, also there were a few mistakes in the question posted, I have done the corrections now, Can you please check again? I have posted the question again with more details [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412382/solution-for-a-system-of-quadratic-and-trigonometric-equations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=X_2-X_1$ and $y=Y_2-Y_1$. From the givens,

$$ y = x \tan\psi, \>\>\>\>\> d= x\frac{\tan \psi}{\cos(\alpha-\psi)}$$

Plug above into $d = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  to get

$$\cos(\alpha-\psi)=\sin\psi$$

which has the solution $\alpha=\frac \pi2$, or $\alpha = 2\psi -\frac\pi2$. In turn, $\cos\alpha=0$, or $\cos\alpha=\sin2\psi$.

For $\cos\alpha=\sin2\psi$, we have

$$3R^2-d^2+2dR\sin2\psi = 0$$

which leads to

$$d= R\left(\sin2\psi+\sqrt{\sin^22\psi+3}\right)$$

As a result,

$$x = d \frac{\cos(\alpha-\psi)}{\tan\psi}= d \cos\psi= R\cos\psi\left(\sin2\psi+\sqrt{\sin^22\psi+3}\right)$$

The other solution, corresponding to $\cos\alpha=0$,  is $d = \sqrt3 R$, which yields

$$x= \sqrt3 R\cos\psi$$

Comment: I have posted the question again with more details, can you please check. There were mistakes in the question i posted here. [Link for the new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412382/solution-for-a-system-of-quadratic-and-trigonometric-equations)